# How to convert an array of hashes to a human readable string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following output:

```
[{"name"=>"Content-Security-Policy", "value"=>"block-all-mixed-content", "decreasesSecurity"=>false, "increasesSecurity"=>true},
 {"name"=>"Strict-Transport-Security", "value"=>"max-age=31536000", "decreasesSecurity"=>false, "increasesSecurity"=>true},
 {"name"=>"X-Content-Type-Options", "value"=>"nosniff", "decreasesSecurity"=>false, "increasesSecurity"=>true},
 {"name"=>"X-Frame-Options", "value"=>"DENY", "decreasesSecurity"=>false, "increasesSecurity"=>true},
 {"name"=>"Content-Length", "value"=>"258", "decreasesSecurity"=>false, "increasesSecurity"=>false},
 {"name"=>"Retry-Count", "value"=>"0", "decreasesSecurity"=>false, "increasesSecurity"=>false},
 {"name"=>"Date", "value"=>"Sun, 28 Mar 2021 17:10:37 GMT", "decreasesSecurity"=>false, "increasesSecurity"=>false},
 {"name"=>"Content-Type", "value"=>"text/html", "decreasesSecurity"=>false, "increasesSecurity"=>false},
 {"name"=>"X-Xss-Protection", "value"=>"1", "decreasesSecurity"=>false, "increasesSecurity"=>true}]
```

These are headers from an HTTP response, and I just want to convert it into a "human readable" format, such as:

```
Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=xxxx
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could iterate the array and print each line which would need less memory than your version:

```
value["headers"].each { |h| puts "#{h['name']}: #{h['value']}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following as a quick solution:

```
puts value["headers"].map {|h| "#{h['name']}: #{h['value']}"}.join("\n")
# =>
Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 258
Retry-Count: 0
Date: Sun, 28 Mar 2021 17:10:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
X-Xss-Protection: 1
```